# Create a `FileOutputStream` out of a location in a remote server

Tags: java, locking

I'm attempting to create a trans-JVM lock. In order to do that, I would like to create a `java.io.FileOutputStream` out of a location in a remote linux server such as this one:

`some_remote_server.mybiz.com:/tmp/.lock`

like so:

```
String locStr = "???"
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(locStr)
FileLock fl = fos.getChannel().tryLock()
```

how should I fill in `???`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to create a `FileOutputStream` directly on a remote location. You have a few options though.

- Use seomthing like NFS to mount the file system on the remote server on the local file system where your JVM runs
- Use a HTTP API on your remote server instead of the file system
- Use something like ZooKeeper, which is a "real" solution for managing distributed locks
- Use a lock in your database, which would be similar to ZooKeeper. For example, PostgreSQL lets you make locks with `SELECT FOR UPDATE`.

Comment: thank you for that, August! I based my question on [this blog](http://oraclejavasecure.blogspot.com/2013/10/java-synchronization-and-concurrency.html) that references a Windows fileshare server (\\server\dir). There is no mention of mounting it to a local filesystem. I wonder if there's a way I could do something like your first bullet point w/o mounting to a local filesystem.

Comment: AFAIK, when you talk to `\\server\dir` on Windows, Windows will under the hood mount it as a local file system with credential checks etc before you can access it